# Qual código usar para que a Logo do meu site HTML fique na mesma linha do menu

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando fazer com que a imagem que coloquei, no caso o logotipo, fique no canto superior esquerdo da página HTML, e ao lado direito o menu principal, sem nenhum tipo de espaço entre eles.
Porém quando insiro a imagem, o menu automaticamente fica embaixo dela. Há algum estilo CSS que possa solucionar o problema?
Tenho o seguinte código em HTML:

````
<html> 
<head>
    <img src="logoempresa.jpg" widht="150px"  height="250px" title="Infotec" >
    <style type="text/css">

        body {
    background-color: lightblue; 
  } 
  h1 { 
    color: black; 
    padding: 60px; 
  }
  body{
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
  }

  #menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #0A6FF0;
    list-style: none;
  }
  #menu ul li{
    display: inline;<!para ficar em linha-->
  }
  #menu ul li a{
   padding: 30px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  #menu ul li a:hover{
    color: #69EEE8;
  }
 


</style>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title> </title>


</head>
<body>
  <div = id="menu"> <!pois vai ser estilizado-->
    <ul>
        <li><a href = "#">Início</a></li> <!hashtag para significar que nao ira a lugar nenhum-->
        <li><a href="#">Cursos</li>
        <li><a href = "#">Professores</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Produtos</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Contatos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>


<h1> </h1>
<h1><font size="1"></font></p>
<footer> </footer>
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você quer apenas que a logo fique ao lado esquerdo do menu, você pode usar a propriedade `display` no **body**:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

E como resultado você terá:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A propriedade `flex` torna o elemento um *flex container*, automaticamente transformando todos os seus filhos diretos em flex itens.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda Algeu! O meu menu agora está ao lado da logo, como na foto que você colocou, porém ficou na posição vertical. Você sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Consegui! Bastou apenas colocar no menu ul position: absolute; Obrigada!!

Comment: @GabriellaRodrigues, fico feliz em ter ajudado. Se a resposta lhe ajudou, peço que marque a resposta como solução. :)